# Python 3. ElementTree. кодировка XML

Tags: python, xmlparser, кодировка

ситуация такая: скрипту через стандартный ввод прилетает XML в кодировке отличной от UTF-8.
Я вычитываю XML и отдаю его парсеру:

```
tree = ET.XML(xml_data)
```

Как задать кодировку данных XML?

P.S. Имеется в виду задать кодировку парсеру или чтоб он сам ее взял из заголовка XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В python 3 все строки хранятся по умолчанию в юникоде.
Если xml_data - строка (тип), то закодировать её в массив байт в кодировке utf-8 можно так -  `xml_data.encode('utf-8')`. Если же это массив байт в какой-то кодировке, то раскодировать и на выходе получить строку в юникоде можно так - `xml_data.decode('coding')`.

Comment: Это вариант, но я имел в виду другое. Обновил вопрос :)

Comment: Ну собственно ответ всё равно тот же ). Этот парсер использует внутри себя http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/pyexpat.html#module-xml.parsers.expat. Когда передаётся строка парсеру, он парсит заголовок и понимает автоматически кодировку.

Comment: Да, ты абсолютно прав. Он сам понимает правильно кодировку. Проблема оказалась у меня в том, что XML прилетал с заданой в заголовке кодировкой cp1251, а в реале он был utf8.